# Check if the next row in a CSV has the same ID as the value in the current row

Tags: python, json, csv, json-normalize

I'm working on a project to read purchase data from a CSV, and output JSON for an API payload. There are multiple lines with the same order ID, as each of them have a separate item, and I would like to combine the items into a single array before creating the purchase payload.

```
order id             name    product_code   purchase_price
012006251700-68811   item1   321618         1380
012006251700-68811   item1   321618         690
012006241026-13750   item2   329452         1490
012006221101-40527   item3   326353         1990
012006221101-40527   item4   321625         1490
012006192158-63823   item5   323098         1990
012006192158-63823   item6   320923         590
012006192158-63823   item7   325051         590
012006192158-63823   item8   325446         1990
```

I've been able to import the rows from the CSV, and am checking the ID value of the current purchase, but haven't been able to get the results I would like to get.

The code below should check if the ID value is the same for the next row and if so, only add the item details to an items array.

If the next row does not have the same ID, the else statement will add the complete purchase to the purchases array.

```
import csv
import json

output = {'purchases': []}
items = {'items': []}
purchaseBody = {}
current_purchase = None

with open('tester - tester.csv') as csv_file:
    for purchase in csv.DictReader(csv_file):
        if current_purchase is not None and purchase['id'] == current_purchase['id']:
            items['items'].append({'id': purchase['id'],
                                  'name': purchase['name'],
                                  'product_code': purchase['product_code']
                                  'purchase_price': purchase['purchase_price'],
                                  })
                 
        else:

            purchaseBody = {
                'id': purchase['id'],
                'user': {'email': purchase['email']},
                'total': purchase['total'],
                'createdAt': purchase['createdAt']
                }
            items['items'].append({'id': purchase['id'],
                                  'name': purchase['name'],
                                  'product_code': purchase['product_code']
                                  'purchase_price': purchase['purchase_price'],
                                  })
            output['purchases'].append(purchaseBody)
            items = {'items': []}   
            purchaseBody.update(items)


        current_purchase = purchase


with open('file.json', 'w') as jsonfile:
    json.dump(output, jsonfile, ensure_ascii=False)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

The desired output should look similar to the following:

```py
{
    
    "purchases": [{
    
        "id": "purchase id",
    
        "user": {
    
            "email": "email"
    
        },
    
        "items": [{
    
                "id": "id1",
    
                "name": "name1",
    
                "additionalFields": {
    
                    "product_code": "product_code1",
    
                    "purchase_price": "purchase_price1"
    
                }
    
            },
    
            {
    
                "id": "id2",
    
                "name": "name2",
    
                "additionalFields": {
    
                    "product_code": "product_code2",
    
                    "purchase_price": "purchase_price2"
    
                }
    
            }
    
        ],
    
        "total": "total",
    
        "createdAt": "createdAt"
    
    }]
    
}
```

Comment: Your code is looping through the lines of the `csv` one at a time. It follows that you can't examine the next line. But you *can* check if the current line matches the previous line.

Comment: There are fields in the expected output that are not reflected in the csv. Please update the sample csv to reflect all of the information it should contain.

Answer (score 2):

- Consider using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html#)
- Use [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to select the groups

  - When `.groupby` is performed on a single column, the group is returned as a `str`, and if `.groupby` is performed on a multiple columns, a `tuple` is returned.
  - `o_id` is the `str` that represents the value used to `groupby`
  - `o_id` must be a `list` or `tuple` in order to `zip` with `groupby_list` to create a `dict`.
  - `d` is the dataframe for each `groupby` group.
- Use [`.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) to iterate through the rows of each group

  - Returns `index` represented by the first `_`, because it's not needed
  - Returns `data`, from which the labels in `groupby_list` are dropped, then convert the remainder to a `dict` using [`.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html), and append it to the `list`, `att_list`
  - After looping through all rows of the group, assign `items_list` as the value to `group['items']`
- Once each group has been iterated through, append the `dict`, `group`, to `dict_list`.
- `dict_list` can be converted back to a dataframe with the following:

  - `df = pd.json_normalize(dict_list, 'items', meta=groupby_list)`

### Expected output

```py
{'items': [{'name': 'item6', 'product_code': '323098', 'purchase_price': 1990},
           {'name': 'item7', 'product_code': '3209233', 'purchase_price': 590}],
 'orderId': '012006192158-63823'}
```

### Code to produce expected output

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

# read in the file
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

dict_list = list()
groupby_list = ['order id']

for o_id, d in df.groupby(groupby_list):
    if type(o_id) != tuple:
        o_id = [o_id]
    group = dict(zip(groupby_list, o_id))
    items_list = list()
    for _, data in d.iterrows():
        data = data.drop(labels=groupby_list)
        items_list.append(data.to_dict())
    group['items'] = items_list
    dict_list.append(group)

# save to a file
with open('test.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(dict_list, f, ensure_ascii=False)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

### Final Output: `dict_list`

```py
[{
        'items': [{
                'name': 'item6',
                'product_code': 323098,
                'purchase_price': 1990
            }, {
                'name': 'item7',
                'product_code': 320923,
                'purchase_price': 590
            }, {
                'name': 'item8',
                'product_code': 325051,
                'purchase_price': 590
            }, {
                'name': 'item9',
                'product_code': 325446,
                'purchase_price': 1990
            }
        ],
        'order id': '012006192158-63823'
    }, {
        'items': [{
                'name': 'item4',
                'product_code': 326353,
                'purchase_price': 1990
            }, {
                'name': 'item5',
                'product_code': 321625,
                'purchase_price': 1490
            }
        ],
        'order id': '012006221101-40527'
    }, {
        'items': [{
                'name': 'item3',
                'product_code': 329452,
                'purchase_price': 1490
            }
        ],
        'order id': '012006241026-13750'
    }, {
        'items': [{
                'name': 'item1',
                'product_code': 321618,
                'purchase_price': 1380
            }, {
                'name': 'item2',
                'product_code': 321618,
                'purchase_price': 690
            }
        ],
        'order id': '012006251700-68811'
    }
]
```

### `test.csv`

```py
order id,name,product_code,purchase_price
012006251700-68811,item1,321618,1380
012006251700-68811,item2,321618,690
012006241026-13750,item3,329452,1490
012006221101-40527,item4,326353,1990
012006221101-40527,item5,321625,1490
012006192158-63823,item6,323098,1990
012006192158-63823,item7,320923,590
012006192158-63823,item8,325051,590
012006192158-63823,item9,325446,1990
```

Comment: The `Expected Output` shown here is what was left in a comment by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

In the code in the question, I think it will do what you want by indenting the line

```
 current_purchase = purchase
```

so that it's inside the `else` block.

However, this kind of task - iterating over a collection and grouping by a key - can be simplified by using the [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function can be used.  Given a sorted collection, it will do the grouping for you.  The [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) function can be used to reduce the amount of code required to get values from the row dictionaries.

```py
import csv
import itertools
import operator
import json

output = {'purchases': []}

reader = csv.DictReader(buf)

# Sort the rows by `id` - if the data is not guaranteed to be sorted.
# If the order id guaranteed, pass `reader` to itertools.groupby.
keyfunc = operator.itemgetter('id')
rows = sorted(reader, key=keyfunc)

# Make a function to build the item dictionaries.
item_keys = ('id', 'name')
item_values = operator.itemgetter(*item_keys)
additional_keys = ('product_code', 'purchase_price')
additional_values = operator.itemgetter(*additional_keys)


def build_item(purchase):
    item = dict(zip(item_keys, item_values(purchase)))
    item['additionalFields'] = dict(zip(additional_keys, additional_values(purchase)))
    return item


for _, purchases in itertools.groupby(rows, keyfunc):
    # Get the first row, because we need some of the data to build purchaseBody.
    purchase = next(purchases)
    # Initialise the items dict with data from the first purchase, and add the rest.
    items = [build_item(purchase)]
    items.extend(build_item(purchase) for p in purchases)
    purchaseBody = {
        'id': purchase['id'],
        'user': {'email': purchase['email']},
        'total': sum(float(item['additionalFields']['purchase_price']) for item in items),
        'createdAt': '2020-08-02',
        'items': items,
    }
    output['purchases'].append(purchaseBody)

with open('file.json', 'w') as jsonfile:
    json.dump(output, jsonfile, ensure_ascii=False)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```